# trouble with date calculation: error: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to perform some calculations with dates. The code is pulling some dates from the database, and here is a portion of the code in my controller:

```
foreach ($tasks as $key => $value) {
    print_r($tasks);
    if ($key == 'start') {
        $start_task = strtotime($value); \\ problematic line
        echo 'start task: '.$start_task.'<br />';
    }
    $task_elapsed = $start_hold - $start_task;
}
```

The $tasks array is a row from a record in the database, and the 'start' field is a timestamp. $start_hold is also a timestamp.

When this tries to execute, I get the following:

The array that prints out is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 800 [serial] => 12 [process] => 4 [start] => 2014-03-03 10:18:22 etc...
```

The error I get is:

```
 strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. I'm trying to convert the timestamp into a format that I can then perform calculations on.

Can anyone tell me the correct method to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

```
$start_task = strtotime($value);
```

with

```
$start_task = strtotime($value->start);
```

Comment: if this is the case, i don't see how $key could ever be "start" - you would never get to strtotime line and there would be no error. or am i missing something?

Comment: Tried that; now I'm getting the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: put print_r($value); just before the line with strtotime, let's see what's in there.

Comment: `print_r($value)` yields: 1

Comment: @ChristinaHugginsRamey, You need to nest down further. Can you post the output of `var_export($tasks)` before the `foreach` on the question ?

Comment: output of var_export($tasks): `array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => '818', 'serial' => '18', 'process' => '4', 'start' => '2014-03-03 13:03:33', 'finish' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'complete' => 'yes', 'hold' => 'yes', 'notes' => ' Put on hold.', 'username' => '', )), 1 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => '819', 'serial' => '18', 'process' => '34', 'start' => '2014-03-03 13:03:33', 'finish' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'complete' => 'yes', 'hold' => 'yes', 'notes' => ' Put on hold.', 'username' => '', )), 2 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => '820',...etc.`

Comment: @ChristinaHugginsRamey See this demo. https://eval.in/108710  So I guess it should be `$start_task = strtotime($value['start']);`

Comment: Tried that, I got the following error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.`

Answer (score 0):

if $tasks is an array of objects (as print_r suggests), perhaps this should work:

```
foreach ($tasks as $object) {
    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'start') {
            $start_task = strtotime($value);
            echo 'start task: '.$start_task.'<br />';
        }

        $task_elapsed = $start_hold - $start_task;
    }
}
```